# Positionning a image to the top of screen with ContraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

i looking to align to the top of screen a simple image with ConstraintLayout. I just tried:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagecookie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/before_cookie"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

The pict is positionning in the middle of screen.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the top of your `ImageView` to the `bottom` of the parent (ConstraintLayout), you need to set it to the top

**EDIT** Sample with the whole layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel for your reply, my image doesn't display anymore it seems the image's bottom is on the top of screen, but with layout_constraintTop_toTopOf it should not?!

Maybe cause of: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. That happens because we have `layout_height` as `0dp` and that means `match_constraints` so the `height` would be defined by the constraints. I edited the response and added `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and with that would be ok. Another solution would be set the `height` to `wrap_content` and let that property by the image itself

Comment: i do code with android studio, and the solution to place my image at the top of the screen is bugging. One time it is well positioned and other time it is bad placed with same code... WTF with this software?

Comment: That's weird. I edited the answer and added the full layout with a sample and an image with the result :) I hope that helps you!

Comment: I just read that with android studio, it's recommend to not use coding to set constraint. And indeed, its bugging if i use design mode and coding. Whatever... thank for your time i get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for you time and help but it still not positioned at the top of screen.
i put my picture at the top of the screen (and middle horizontal) with:

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imagecookie"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/suzuki"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```